# Deutschebahn API for departureboard not showing destination station

Tags: arrays

From this link:

https://developer.deutschebahn.com/store/apis/info?name=Fahrplan-Free&version=v1&provider=DBOpenData#!/default/get_departureBoard_id

I can successfully call the `ARRIVALboard` information:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ICE 1689",
    "type": "ICE",
    "boardId": null,
    "stopId": 8000152,
    "stopName": "Hannover Hbf",
    "dateTime": "2021-01-19T00:00",
    "origin": "Hamburg-Altona",
    "track": "8",
    "detailsId": "78642%2F27599%2F82706%2F15139%2F80%3fstation_evaId%3D8000152"
  }
```

, which is complete.

However, when I call the `DEPARTUREboard` information I get everything apart from the 'destination' JSON field.

```
{
    "name": "ICE 272",
    "type": "ICE",
    "boardId": null,
    "stopId": 8000152,
    "stopName": "Hannover Hbf",
    "dateTime": "2021-01-19T00:05",
    "track": "7",
    "detailsId": "972312%2F330581%2F159824%2F244192%2F80%3fstation_evaId%3D8000152"
  }
```

, i.e., the 'destination' field is missing according to the [Model schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEgaZ.png)

I guess this is a user error but I can't work out how to fix this!

Comment: There is no `destination` field. Did you mean: `origin`?

Comment: yes, 'origin' apologies for not making this clear